# Is there a way to score fuzzy hits with the same score as exact hits?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use elasticsearch as a integration tool which can match records from different sources. I'm combining filters and query for this. Filters are filtering out irrevelant records and putting trough candidate matches. Then out of those candidates all are being scored. I'm using fuzzy match because some of the records might contain a misspell (Nicolson Way/Nicholson Way). I would like them to be scored equally with disregard if its a fuzzy match or equal match.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-scoring.html

Is there a way to achieve this with Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `constant_score` to give it a score of your choice:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "query": {
          "fuzzy": {"text": "whatever"}
        }
      },
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What about this scenario: The text may have multiple words and if more words are found I want to get higher score for those. But I don't want to exceed score of 5. The procedure would be ((wordsFound/totalWordsInQuery)*maxFixedScore). Your solution will result in partial matches having the same score as exact matches.